# Using API Gateway/Lambda function to handle CNAME requests from various domains

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm wondering if I could configure my API Gateway and Lambda function to handle incoming connections from a CNAME. Consider the following:

- Request is made to `example.com` which has a CNAME set to `api.mydomain.com`
- `api.mydomain.com` has a Custom Domain Mapping in API Gateway
- The Method Request on my endpoint mapping takes the requesting domain and calls the Lambda function with a JSON model of the calling CNAME (`example.com`)
- Function performs its logic then responds to the request

What I'm trying to do is use the Lambda as a way to interpret requests from other domains so that I don't have to manually configure the mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `domainName` from `requestContext`

Create lambda below, Add API gateway.

Then you can find out useful information you want.

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(event["requestContext"]["domainName"])
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to figure out how to access RequestContext in Go though.

Answer (score 0):

> *so that I don't have to manually configure the mappings*

This can't be avoided.  Unless API Gateway has a custom domain mapping configured the hostname found in the HTTP `Host` header and TLS SNI -- which will be example.com in this case -- your request will arrive at a pool of AWS servers that do not know how to handle it, because you haven't configured it, and it will not invoke the Lambda function.

Additionally, you'll need a matching SSL certificate attached to the API Gateway custom domain.

Comment: Yup, had to go the path of writing configuration tooling to set these up on-demand. Sigh.